# What version of Ubuntu should I install on my laptop?

Tags: system-installation, cpu

my laptop is an Acer Extensa 5620Z
Intel Pentium dual core T2310
(1.46 GHz, 533 MHz FSB, 1M L2 cache)
2 GB DDR2
I wanted to install Linux, and forget about wimdows.
Well, install the Ubuntu version 16.04 x 64,
Passing the command "lscpu" tells me that the pc is compatible with 32-bit and 64-bit, but it goes very slowly, it gets a lot stuck.
I do not know if I should install another version, if they offer me some idea and where to read information on how to do a correct installation.
Maybe the question has little basis, but I have read information and I am very lost, formatting maybe I did not choose the most optimal options to use the computer in programming, and as I say, now I look for information, but everything I read did not leave the subject Clear.
Forgive syntax and vocabulary, but I must make use of the translator.
Thank you.

Comment: Thanks for the support, check the other question but it is not very clear to me.
I'll keep looking until I find a solution.
Thank you

Comment: All versions of Ubuntu will run; I have 16.04 LTS running on a single-core pentium-M (slower than yours, & only 1.5gb ddr memory).  I would however **not** run Unity (default DEsktop in 16.04) or Gnome (default DE in 18.04), instead having loaded LXDE (Lubuntu equiv), XFCE (Xubuntu equiv) & MATE (Ubuntu-MATE). The DEsktop in my opinion matters more...  (*LXDE uses the least memory; but I prefer MATE & XFCE so select at login time which I use..*)

Comment: I agree with @guiverc on that: the desktop is more important. I would partition my system up in parts and install Ubuntu, lUbuntu, xUbuntu and Mate in each and then start a trial run of a few days with each of them. Delete what you do not like and then re-partition to one disk and install the one I want to use. The link though that pomsky posted will be your best guide.

Comment: The last two comments from @Rinzwind and guiverc I  clarified a bit more things.
I'm using it for programming purposes, until I can have a better machine.
If they answer, and they tell me a version to download, I will be happy to accept.
It gives me the doubt of how to make the parts of the disk, if they tell me where to read about it.
Thank you and forgive my ignorance, maybe I have not studied Linux enough.
Thank you.

Comment: Programming what? I use Ubuntu on a google cloud instance for my coding (and my notebook to connect with putty and an ssh key) ;-) Your system wont work well with mysql and apache :P

Comment: Developing with Node.js and an Express server